# Proving $\forall x \forall y(R(x,y) \to R(y,x)) \therefore \forall x \forall y\forall z[(R(x,y) \wedge R(x,z)) \to \exists u(R(y,u) \wedge R(z,u))]$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Working on Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 297, exercise B. 4), appears this exercise:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\forall x \forall y(R(x,y) \to R(y,x))}{
 \fitch{R(a,b) \wedge R(a,c)}{
   R(a,b) \to R(b,a)\\
   R(a,c) \to R(c,a)\\
   R(a,b)\\
   R(b,a)\\
   R(a,c)\\
   R(c,a)\\
   R(b,a) \wedge R(c,a)\\
   \exists u(R(b,u) \wedge R(c,u))
 }\\
 (R(a,b) \wedge R(a,c)) \to \exists u(R(b,u) \wedge R(c,u))\\
 \forall z[(R(a,b) \wedge R(a,z)) \to \exists u(R(b,u) \wedge R(z,u))]\\
 \forall y \forall z[(R(a,y) \wedge R(a,z)) \to \exists u(R(y,u) \wedge R(z,u))]\\
 \forall x \forall y \forall z[(R(x,y) \wedge R(x,z)) \to \exists u(R(y,u) \wedge R(z,u))]\\
}
$

Is this proof correct ? Am I allowed to apply $\mathbf{\forall E}$ twice on lines 3,4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly, NO, not in a standard Fitch-style system. Look again at the official statement of the $\forall$E rule. You instantiate one variable at a time. Hence it takes two steps to get line (3).

Applying $\forall$E to the premiss once gets you to e.g.

$\forall y(R(a, y) \to R(y, a))$

And then another step takes you to the desired

$(R(a, b) \to R(b, a))$.

Similarly it takes two steps to get line (4).

Comment: +1  Glad to see you around, @PeterSmith.

Comment: Thanks @amWhy ... I'm hoping to be around here more again, now a book's finished :)

Comment: Ahh, what's the title of your new book, and when can I expect to find it? :)  All your online work is phenomenal, so I have no doubt that your most recent work is as well.

Comment: Not very exciting I'm afraid. Just the second edition of my very intro logic book: https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl/ifl2nd/

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Are you a philosopher by training?  I just ask because that was where I earned my first PhD: philosophy with a heavy emphasis on logic.  Then I delved into mathematics and math logic.  You are so very articulate, and have no doubt helped thousands upon thousands through your book, blog, and on this site, and wherever else you've taught. My first love still remains with philosophy.

Comment: Did the maths tripos including Part III before becoming a philosopher of sorts, so really just another Trinity mathmo ...

Comment: To me honest, it's hard for me to imagine not being part philosopher/part mathematician.  But that's also true of some of my colleagues who may be physicists, but at a philosophical level, etc. with other colleagues.  But in the end, I believe the closest alliance is between mathematics and philosophy.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterSmith. I understood your correction. Is my proof correct, now ?
[Fitch Proof](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrw2bhoh4fuvlw6/prove.png?dl=0)